# Cannot run 'npm run build' with pinia nuxt3 project

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia

I am trying to install pinia into nuxt3 project. All tutorials I have found so far says to install 2 packages, 'pinia' and '@pinia/nuxt'. All examples import defineStore from 'pinia' package. So I have added pinia package in package.json and run npm install. Directly calling 'npm install pinia' not working (maybe related or not. I don't know). Also installed '@pinia/nuxt' (without any issue).

In short, when I call 'npm run build', I am getting this error.

```
Rollup error: Could not load ... /node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs/dist/pinia.mjs (imported by .nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs) : ENOTDIR: not a directory, open ... node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs/dist/pinia.mjs
```

Comment: What is not working when you install it? Did you checked the documentation rather than the tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be fixed with the latest version of @pinia/nuxt 0.4.1 https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/6846

So I would suggest updating your @pinia/nuxt package and updating your nuxt version to the latest RC